# Optimize algorithm to compute orbit under a given action in python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, memory

My goal is to iterate through a set S of elements given a single element and an action G: S -> S that acts transitively on S (i.e., for any elt,elt' in S, there is a map f in G such that f(elt) = elt'). The action is finitely generated, so I can use that I can apply each generator to a given element.

The algorithm I use is:

```
def orbit(act,elt):
    new_elements  = [elt]
    seen_elements = set([elt])
    yield elt
    while new_elements:
        elt = new_elements.pop()
        seen_elements.add(elt)
        for f in act.gens():
            elt_new = f(elt)
            if elt_new not in seen_elements:
                new_elements.append(elt_new)
                seen_elements.add(elt_new)
                yield elt_new
```

This algorithm seems to be well-suited and very generic. BUT it has one major and one minor slowdown in big computations that I would like to get rid of:

> The major: seen_elements collects all the elements, and is thus too memory consuming, given that I do not need the actual elements anymore.
>
> How can I achieve to not have all the elements stored in memory?

Very likely, this depends on what the elements are. So for me, these are short lists (<10 entries) of ints (each < 10^3). So first, is there a fast way to associate a (with high probability) unique integer to such a list? Does that save much memory? If so, should I put those into a dict to check the containment (in this case, first the hash equality test, and then an int equality test are done, right?), or how should I do that?

> the minor: poping the element takes a lot of time given that I don't quite need that list. Is there a better way of doing that?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: What about getting rid of `seen_elements` and making `new_elements` a set? This way you just add to it. The only problem is that you would always yield `elt_new`, regardless of the fact that it is a duplicate or not. I don't know if you can solve this problem.

Comment: This way, the algorithm will never terminate. Also, it is anyway essential to iterate through that set of elements, so seeing an element twice or more is not an option. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why wouldn't it terminate? If `new_elements` is a set it won't have duplicates.

Comment: True, but then I remove an element from `new_elements` (which is currently done in the `.pop()`, and that element will be added to the set later again.

Comment: I am sure there is a solution to that problem. One would be to have an injective map from the set `S` to integers and to use those (which I would hope to use less or even much less memory).

Comment: *"is there a fast way to associate a (with high probability) unique integer to such a list"* -- `hash(tuple(list))`?

Comment: if your code works (produces the correct result eventually) then you could ask how you can improve its performance on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: the first `seen_elements.add(elt)` is unnecessary in your code

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The set `S` has, in my case, millions of entries, each being a tuple of 8 ints. Do you see any good reason why the hash of the tuple would be unique on those with very high probability?

Comment: Look up the properties of a good hash function and judge for yourself. Unrelated, consider whether you could use Bloom filter in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So first, is there a fast way to associate a (with high probability) unique integer to such a list?

If the list entries all are in `range(1, 1024)`, then `sum(x << (i * 10) for i, x in enumerate(elt))` yields a unique integer.

> Does that save much memory?

The short answer is yes. The long answer is that it's complicated to determine how much. Python's long integer representation uses (probably) 30-bit digits, so the digits will pack 3 to the 32-bit word instead of 1 (or 0.5 for 64-bit). There's some object overhead (8/16 bytes?), and then there's the question of how many of the list entries require separate objects, which is where the big win may lie.

If you can tolerate errors, then a Bloom filter would be a possibility.

> the minor: popping the element takes a lot of time given that I don't quite need that list. Is there a better way of doing that?

I find that claim surprising. Have you measured?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! A `%prun` shows that in one case I am interested, there are `1062882` calls of that `.pop()` with a total time consumption of `80 secs` out of `259.260 secs` for the complete computation.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Bloom filters, that seems to be exactly what I need, thanks! In case anyone is interested: your above way results in a slowdown of `200 secs` in this example.

Comment: The memory issue remained after using a Bloom filter. Then I realized that my `new_elements` list was containing almost all elements (i.e., the algo very soon constructed most of the elements, with almost all yet to be tested). Since the above encoding in one int is invertible, I also had to encode the elements in `new_elements` to get down the amount of memory.